# Apache Mod-rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

This gives "No record found"

```
###Get members pagename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /view_members_public_profile.php?page_name=$1 [L]


But this shows member record
http://localhost/view_members_public_profile.php?page_name=mabel
```

I want to show members profile by going to http://localhost/mabel

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you bothered to check what it *is* doing?

Comment: Yes I did. "No record found".

Comment: That's not what it's *doing*, that is the *result*.

Answer (score 0):

try `RewriteRule ^/(.*) /view_members_public_profile.php?page_name=$1 [L]`